# what is the difference between () and [] dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain the difference between the following two forms and what does each do:

```
int *p = new int[5];
```

and

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

**Query**

1) What are we allocating in both the cases i.e either integer or array ??

2) What will be the initial value after allocation in both cases??

3) And reference from where i can found about this

Answer (score 10):

The syntax of a *new-expression* is as follows:

1. the keyword `new`
2. optional arguments, enclosed in parentheses
3. type
4. optional initializer

In `new int[5]`, the type is `int[5]` and there is no initializer. Thus, an array of 5 `int`s is allocated, they are not initialized, and a pointer to the first element is returned.

In `new int(5)`, the type is `int` and the initializer is `(5)`, so one `int` is allocated, it is initialized with the value 5 (just like in `int x(5);`), and a pointer to it is returned.

Comment: "*they are not initialized..*" ... Pedantically speaking, they're actually default initialized which in case of built-in types means uninitialized.

Comment: @Nawaz This is only true for types inaccessible outside the scope of a class or method due to compatibility with C. Also, they are not default initialized, but zero initialized.

Comment: @xvdiff: You're wrong. Search *"default initialization, zero initialization and value initialization"* on this site, you'll get many topics discussing them.

Comment: @Nawaz Welp, seems I misunderstood that one. Back to the books.

Answer (score 6):

```
int *p = new int[5];
```

allocates an "array" of integers with length 5. It returns a pointer to the beginning of 5 contiguous memory blocks, each of which can hold an `int`.

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

allocates a pointer to a *single* integer initialized to the value 5.

Answer (score 3):

In the first instance it allocates a integer array of size 5. In this case, the elements in the array are uninitialized.

In the second instance it allocates one integer with value 5.

References:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/

Answer (score 3):

here I will answer all questions one by one

Question 1:What are we allocating in both the cases i.e either integer or array ??

```
int *p = new int[5]; // you are allocating an array
int *p = new int(5); // you are allocating an integer
```

Question 2:What will be the initial value after allocation in both cases?

```
int *p = new int[5]; // Initially there will be random value on all indexes
int *p = new int(5); // Initially value will be 5
```

Question 3:And reference from where i can found about this?

Check the following links

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_%28programming%29

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets are used to denoting arrays of its elements.
So in this statement

```
int *p = new int[5];
```

There is allocated an array of 5 integer  elements that are not initialized. Compare with definition

```
int a[5];
```

In this statement

```
int *p = new int(5);
```

there is allocated an object of type int that is initialized by 5. Compare it with the following definition

```
int x = int( 5 );
```

or simply

```
int x = 5;
```